# Cannot append script type text/wreq into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am able to append scripts that has no type or whose `type="text/javascript"` but not this script `type="text/wreq"`

my iframe tag is

```
<iframe id="result-iframe" allowfullscreen="true" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms" allowtransparency="true" class="result-iframe"></iframe>
```

and I am appending the scripts using this syntax

```
var head = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/wreq';
script.src = '/wreq.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

I believe the syntax is correct as other insertion of scripts are working any help will be appreciated thanks....

Comment: I am unfamiliar with what wreq is, but what parses it?

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/substack/wreq for bundling my js libs.